# SSH can't resolve domain?

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, putty

Good evening ladys and gentlemen,

I set up a subdomain on FreeDNS to connect to my server via PuTTY. When i try to connect via to the domain it timesout, it was working yesterday (using the domain) and i haven't touched any of the server's networking since initial creation of the server.

if i use the IP of the server it connects fine.

**nslookup produces the server's IP** however PuTTY just seems unable to do so.

im at a loss for what to do

per usual, any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: Curiously, i try to resolve the domain and the IP is different from the one i set in the record (double checked). even when i delete and reinstate the record it gets resolved to a different IP. im assuming the domain per se is buggered to high heaven, gonna to use a different domain and see if the problem rears it's head again.

2ND EDIT:
after the first edit i did a nslookup (using the bad domain) via centralops and it reported the correct IP from the afraid nameservers: [Correct IP nameserver/s (ns1 through 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndESS.png)

Okayyy then, maybe it's a propagation issue? then i check again and i get the same (incorrect) IP from a completely different nameserver: [Incorrect IP nameserver/s (ns1 through 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afIPm.png)

the incorrect IP's location shows it's very close/smack bang on the datacenter that hosts my server. i know this means something but im still in the dark into what the issue could be or if i could even remedy it

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=ssh+resolve

Comment: When putty fails to connect, what is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: "Network error: Connection timed out", came back to the thread because it's happend again and rebooting didn't solve it this time

Comment: How exactly do you use `nslookup`? (One parameter: the target hostname, or two?)

Comment: Just the one, i wasn't aware you could enter more than one

Comment: Did you increment the DNS serial number in the SOA record when you updated the domain? (`nslookup -type=soa contoso.com 1.1.1.1`, where `contoso.com` is the domain entry and `1.1.1.1` is one of your target nameservers) If not, the nameservers won't know your domain got updated

Comment: I don't have that level of access to the server. i can only declare the subdomain, and the IP to point to (as a A record)

Answer (score 0):

Check you ufw/firewalld rules on SSH server.

Add debug info from SSH connect:
Configuring PuTTY Debug Logs:

```
   From the PuTTY Configuration, in the left pane, click on  "Logging" under "Session".
   On the right, ensure "Log all session output" or "Log SSH packet data" is selected.
   Note the path to the log file which needs to be sent along with sshd logs.
```

Configuring ssh Debug Logs (at the Unix shell)

```
   Simply add "-vvv" (three "v" 's) to your normal ssh command; for example:
   ssh -vvv username@servername
```

You can add port option with "-p22" parameter